Why is metabase giving this weird error of invalid reference?
SELECT
  count(
    distinct "public"."cnpy_portfolio_current_snapshot"."userid"
  ) AS "count"
FROM
  "public"."cnpy_portfolio_current_snapshot"
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      tenderneutralledgerid as ledgerid,
      userid,
      tnl.merchantprogramid,
      tm.merchantid
    FROM
      tdym_tender_neutral_ledgers as tnl
      INNER JOIN tdym_merchant_programs as tm ON tnl.merchantprogramid = tm.merchantprogramid
      where {{createdat}} 
    UNION
    SELECT
      rewardledgerid as ledgerid,
      userid,
      tm.merchantprogramid,
      tm.merchantid
    FROM
      tdym_reward_ledgers as tl
      INNER JOIN tdym_merchant_programs as tm ON tl.merchantid = tm.merchantid
      where {{createdat}} 
  ) AS "Join all Reward Ledgers - Userid" ON "public"."cnpy_portfolio_current_snapshot"."userid" = "Join all Reward Ledgers - Userid"."userid"
  INNER JOIN "public"."tdym_merchants" ON "Join all Reward Ledgers - Userid"."merchantid" = "public"."tdym_merchants"."merchantid"
 

WHERE {{merchantname}}

I am working on this query, merchantname and createdat are the variables in metabase, but I am repeatedly getting this weird error. Its not just this query, most of the queries i am using feild filter of date variables are giving this error

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ra_orders" Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "a".

I tried in various queries but it didn't work.

There's no reference to ra_orders in your query. Are you getting this exact error every time?

Yes, I am getting this exact error everytime whatever table i use.

I'm not familiar with Metabase, if it were SQL Server I would suspect that a consumed view or stored procedure was the culprit.

@Roshni In metabase it doesn't allow to use the table alias so please remove the table alias and use the table name instead.
